# Remove duplicated HTML attributes with DOM parser

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I have multiple garbage HTML sources that I'd like to fix programatically. They are HTML files with multiple attributes of the same type attached to elements, which is obviously not right in HTML. Example of such tag:

```
<img alt=" " alt="Turtle" src="turtle.png" alt alt="Funny Turtle" alt="">
```

What I'd like to do with this tag is to leave just the first non-empty `alt` attribute (spaces-only are considered empty), like this:

```
<img alt="Turtle" src="turtle.png">
```

If there are just empty or whitespace-only attributes, the attribute can go away.

I was thinking about using regular expression for this task, but it seems to be too error-prone. It's not trivial to avoid removing text looking like an attribute from inside of the tag.

Better solution are DOM parsers, but all I've seen just ignore duplicated attributes, making attributes array associative, so in this case for example:

```
[
    'alt' => ' ',
    'src' => 'turtle.png',
]
```

If only the parser could get all attributes, like this:

```
[
    ['name' => 'alt', 'value' => ' '],
    ['name' => 'alt', 'value' => 'Turtle'],
    ['name' => 'src', 'value' => 'turtle.png'],
    ['name' => 'alt', 'value' => null],
    ['name' => 'alt', 'value' => 'Funny Turtle'],
    ['name' => 'alt', 'value' => ''],
]
```

It would be quite easy to fix it. I'd just go and find the duplicates, then set attibute on the node to the first value.

Are there any DOM parsers getting all attributes, duplicates included?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know suitable parser for php, but as alternative solution you can use python HTMLParser.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag=='img':
            print "tag:", tag, "attrs:",attrs

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><body><h1><img alt=" " alt="Turtle" src="turtle.png" alt alt="Funny Turtle" alt="">Parse me!</h1></body></html>')

# output:
# tag: img attrs: [('alt', ' '), ('alt', 'Turtle'), ('src', 'turtle.png'), ('alt', None), ('alt', 'Funny Turtle'), ('alt', '')]
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting! So Python's HTML parser does that. Does it support CSS-like selectors?

Comment: No, it just parses input and calls user defined handlers for starttag, data, comment, etc.... So there is still lot of work need to be done to achieve your desired result.